# assign variable to list item python

Tags: python, arrays, variables, append

I'm looking for a way to assign a variable to a specific list item by having the same . Here is my code to enlighten things.

```
    count = 0
    beer = 5/100
    maltbeer = 7/100
    tablewine = 12/100
    fortifiedwine = 17/100
    aperitif = 24/100
    spirits = 40/100
    percentageCalc = 0
    for i in drinks:
        count =+ 1
        percentageCalc = percentageCalc + drinks[count]
```

The drinks are inputed into *drinks* and can vary depending on what was inputed.

i.e: drinks = ['beer', 'beer', 'spirits', 'maltbeer']

*drinks* is appended inputs only accepted as one of the variables seen further up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary for the various types of drinks:

```
abv = {"beer": 5
       "maltbeer": 7,
       "tablewine": 12,
       "fortifiedwine": 17,
       "aperitif": 24,
       "spirits": 40}

percentage = 0

for drink in drinks:
    if drink in abv:
        percentage += percentageCalc + abv[drink]
    else:
        print("don't know about %s" % drink)

percentage /= 100.0
```

I also removed the `/100` calculation from the individual items and added at the end, and implemented an error message in case the drink isn't known.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick answer! My teacher having me concentrating on visualbullsh*t has made me forget so much about python. I was foolish to think I could just throw myself back in with ease.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to hold each of the drink types as a dictionary key. The value for each drink is its percentage.

```
drink_strength = {
    'beer': 5/100,
    'maltbeer': 7/100,
    'tablewine': 12/100,
    'fortifiedwine': 17/100,
    'aperitif': 24/100,
    'spirits': 40/100,
}

drinks = ['beer', 'beer', 'spirits', 'maltbeer', 'lemonade']
percentage_calc = sum(drink_strength.get(drink, 0) for drink in drinks)
print(percentage_calc)
```

**Output**

```
0.5700000000000001
```

The percentage is calculated by successively adding the percentages for each drink, or, if the drink is unknown, 0 percent is assumed.

N.B. Above code assumes Python 3. If using Python 2 you can add to the top of your file:

```
from __future__ import division
```

so that, e.g. `7/100` = 0.7 and not 0 as Python 2 integer division would produce.